# how to make the two result(with the same column) from two queries display in a single query table

Tags: sql

I don't know if I made my question understandable,
the situation likes this:
I have two queries, which have the same demand to show the panel Id and left points, but one is for the customer who still earned 2000 points, one is for the customer who already redeemed once, I write the two queries below.

1)

```
select panel_ID,current_points_balance, sum(points_earned) as totalpoint
from Tbl_member, Tbl_member_participation
where tbl_member_participation.member_id = Tbl_member.member_id
group panel_Id, current_points_balance
having totalpoint > 2000
```

2)

```
select panel_ID,current_points_balance, sum(points_earned) as totalpoint
from Tbl_member, Tbl_member_redemption
where tbl_member_redemption.member_id = Tbl_member.member_id
group panel_Id, current_points_balance
```

so my question is how can I combine these two conditions in one query or just show the two results from two query in one table? I don't think I can simply use "or" to combine them, which is the only way I know though.

Comment: UNION will do the solution for you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the keyword UNION and UNION ALL are used to join results from two query with SAME NO OF COLUMNS.

use UNION statement in your query.not sure whether the following works in your database.But give a try and comment me on any issue

```
select panel_ID,current_points_balance, sum(points_earned) as totalpoint
from Tbl_member, Tbl_member_participation
where tbl_member_participation.member_id = Tbl_member.member_id
group panel_Id, current_points_balance
having totalpoint > 2000
UNION
select panel_ID,current_points_balance, sum(points_earned) as totalpoint
from Tbl_member, Tbl_member_redemption
where tbl_member_redemption.member_id = Tbl_member.member_id
group panel_Id, current_points_balance
```

Comment: oh yes!! I just forget this operation, this might work in my database, will let you know. thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine the results of these queries in to a single view, I mean you have two colums panel_ID,current_points_balance and you want to show the results of two queries in the same column itself, then use `UNION`, `UNION ALL`

```
select 
    panel_ID, current_points_balance, 
    sum(points_earned) as totalpoint
from 
    Tbl_member, Tbl_member_participation
where 
    tbl_member_participation.member_id = Tbl_member.member_id
group 
    panel_Id, current_points_balance
having 
    totalpoint > 2000

UNION

select 
    panel_ID,current_points_balance, 
    sum(points_earned) as totalpoint
from 
    Tbl_member, Tbl_member_redemption
where 
    tbl_member_redemption.member_id = Tbl_member.member_id
group 
    panel_Id, current_points_balance
```

Or you can use

```
select 
    panel_ID,current_points_balance, 
    sum(points_earned) as totalpoint
from 
    Tbl_member, Tbl_member_participation
where 
    tbl_member_participation.member_id = Tbl_member.member_id
group 
    panel_Id, current_points_balance
having 
    totalpoint > 2000

UNION ALL

select 
    panel_ID,current_points_balance, 
    sum(points_earned) as totalpoint
from 
    Tbl_member, Tbl_member_redemption
where 
    tbl_member_redemption.member_id = Tbl_member.member_id
group 
    panel_Id, current_points_balance
```

The difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` is nothing but union will eliminate all the duplicate rows and union all will not eliminate duplicate rows

Try this, comment me if any issue is related with this

Comment: thank you for your kind. I posted another question which is still about combine result. I will appreciate if you can help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602356/how-to-combine-different-quires-result-into-a-single-query-result-table